# Docker Swarm setup in Virtualbox

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Team:
Suppose I want to setup Docker Swarm with 3 nodes and currently have Docker Engine running on node-1 (Ubuntu in Virtualbox).
How do I go about creating 2 more nodes? Do I spin up 2 more Ubuntu servers in Virtualbox, install Docker Engine and configure network then run docker swarm commands on node-1?
Or is there a faster way to get this done? Some blogs suggested using Docker Machine but I see its deprecated.
`https://docs.docker.com/machine/`

While Kubernetes would be the best solution, I was exploring Docker Swarm orchestration so any pointers would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setup 3 Ubuntu vms, Docker engine on each.
Run `docker swarm init` on the first, and `docker swarm join` with the token returned on the subsequent nodes. Job done.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I was just exploring if there was any other method to do this. Apparently, there isnt one.

Comment: Well, if your virualization is ESXi or something, you could use Rancher 1 to provision swarm and its vms automatically. But for 3 nodes?